# How to initialize properties of parent class with different value than child

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have below class hierarchy

```
class Category{
  protected int _discount;
}

class SubCategory:Category{
  // some other properties
}

class Item:SubCategory{
  // some more properties
 public Item (int discount){
  _discount = discount;
 } 
}
```

When I initialize Item with below code
    Item item = new Item(10);
It will set _discount as 10 for Item class. I also want to set _discount for SubCategory and Category class with a different value. 
One way is to pass 3 different discount values in Item constructor and assign to parents appropriately.

Another way I can do is by exposing methods in Item class to explicitly set the property values in base classes.

Is there any other solution best suits the OOP concept. Somewhere I am not very comfortable with what I am doing here.

Comment: where is your inheritance?

Comment: Terms like "parent" and "child" are **very misleading** when talking about inheritance in OOP. Rather use terms like "base type/class" and "derived type/class" (or "specialization of base type"). There is no real parent-child relationship between a derived type and the base type it derives from as far as OOP inheritance is concerned.

Comment: @DavidG i was going to answer him with composition, because its what it looks like, but how does he have a _discount without inheriting and not as a property? this cant be the code...

Comment: Really sorry for not specifying inheritance. Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

The `_discount` variable doesn't have a scope so is implicitly `private`. You need to make it accessible by the derived class, in this case you likely want it to be [`protected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) which is defined as (emphasis mine):

> A protected member is accessible within its class and **by derived class instances**.

Which means your code would be:

```
public class Category
{
  protected int _discount;
}
```

Note: This is a very good example of why you should **always** specify scope on all things.